# Can't update a keyring for Xorg (Ubuntu18_04)

Tags: apt

I use Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
Having run command `sudo apt update`, I clashed an obstacle. Please,
see message:

> W: An error occurred during the signature verification.
> The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be
> used. GPG error:
> http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Xorg/xUbuntu_18.04
> InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
> public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1CC4F3FE3558D089

It's supposed that I ought to download a keyring, but which for repo mentioned in the error? Is it something specific?

Comment: You use Ubuntu? Then why do you need a connection to XORG **xUbuntu** from OpenSUSE?  Nevertheless: we can't fix this as is a problem is with the owner of download.opensuse.org Unless the whole repo is wrong: if so remove it.

Comment: @Rinzwind how do I find out the name of repo?